# Does Android 5 or 6 (or future version) have a built-in barcode scanning API like iOS does?

Tags: android, ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

Starting in iOS 7, Apple added a built-in basic barcode scanning with AV Foundation.

Does Android 5 or 6 (or any future version) have anything similar?

Just something basic like UPC, EAN, QR code, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android does not, but the Google Play Services [Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/) does.

To use it, you will need to add the Google Play Services SDK as a dependency in your app, and the end-user will need Google Play Services and Android 4.2.2 or newer installed on their device.

The Vision API currently supports the following formats

- 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
- 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC

Comment: And.. Google Play Services is basically the same as saying 'Android' on almost all devices that people think of as 'Android' ... The only exceptions would be CHEAP tablets (which honestly most of the time aren't worth even buying) and devices from other big parties such as Amazon Fire, etc. (Which is worth it, depending on your needs.) Google has in particular put more and more functionality in Google Play Services and not in "Android" because they want Manf. to NOT go the route of Amazon and the cheap manf. and make their own splinter versions of Android. 1 of 2(?)

Comment: @mawalker There is definitely a lot of overlap, but it is an important distinction to make. China would be the other big exception

Comment: Continued 2 of 2... And the reason why this matters is because to get Google Play Services on your phone/device (as a Manf.) you have to agree to Google's quality requirements and feature requirements (among other things.. which I'm assuming includes paying Google... but..."shrugs").... So 'basically the same' because of Google business practices(which aren't all bad... helps keep splinting down...etc..) ...

@Enrich is correct in that the other big exception is China, but I was referring to most of the devices you can get outside of China/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no... you have to use external projects, like:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

or

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Answer (score 0):

There's no single API to scan a Barcode on Android, and depending on what you want to achieve you've different solutions available.

Personally I categorise the available solutione in three buckets:

- Media Pipeline, something like what is provided by Google Play Service (Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/)
- Simple "scan-a-barcode" API, that is something nowadays you can have with ZXing and its [Intent based interface](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent)
- Professional barcode scanning library like or, more likely a custom HW device that includes an hardware barcode scanners, like devices from Zebra, Honeywell, Panasonic, etc. These solutions always includes a vendor specific library with much higher performance than ZXing using the camera.

[I build a presentation about this some time ago](http://pietromaggi.com/decks/barcodes-api/#/). tldr is: depends what you want to achieve, how many barcodes you need to read and how important is this feature in your solution.

A note regarding devices without Google Play Services (that means, without the [Google Mobile Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_mobile_services), that GPS is a part of): not only cheap devices are sold without GMS, in China the Google services are usually not available and devices do not have it. Another category of devices coming sometimes without GMS are the enterprise rugged devices. Built to be used in line of business scenario, they try to avoid GMS as those are seen more as a burden than anything else.
[This is a niche market where barcode scanning is one of the main feature](http://zebra.com/tc8000)

*disclaymer* I work for Zebra Technologies, maker of Enterprise Rugged Android devices.